# Filter rows in MySQL Select

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I need to filter rows (grouped) that contains a certain element. Let's explain in more detail: I have a set of objects, each one with its own 'object_id', and collections, which it's formed by a subset of objects.

My query try to fetch all collections from a user that the object_id passed as a parameter is not contained in the collection.

My query is:

```
SELECT cn.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM collection_items WHERE collection_id=cn.id) as n_items, 0 as selected, COALESCE(lo.url_thumb, '/img/no-image.png') as image
FROM collection_names as cn LEFT JOIN list_objects as lo ON lo."ID"=cn.image_object_id LEFT JOIN collection_items as ci ON ci.collection_id=cn.id
WHERE cn.user_id=44 AND ci.object_id<>86127
GROUP BY cn."id", lo.url_thumb
```

The query returns all collections. I think it's due to as one collection has many objects and are grouped, the condition is malformed.

Any idea?

**EDIT**:
Let's say I have the following table:

[image]

Applying the select above with the object_id=10, the desired response would be that the collection_id=1 would not be included due to such object_id is yet included, so the response: [2, 3, 4, 5]. I only want to retrieve collections where the object_id passed as parameter is not included.

I hope this clarify it a little bit more.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I hope the picture and comments clarify ir a little bit more.

Comment: I hope that my previous comment proves useful.